# Reading file from External Storage of Android SDK Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator

i am new bie in android,
I am developing an application in Android, and i used some ready made libs, now there is browse option, and when i do browse it gives the place of /mnt/sdcard, it is basiacally a file reader, if i use this app in mobile then i can browse my memory card, but there even 500MB card have been configured in emulator, i dont know where to place the files so i can access in my Emulator's app, i am expecting, there will be a path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SOMEFolder  where i can place my files using computer and can access in my emulator. Attached an image of my emulator
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i dont know where to place the files so i can access in my Emulator's
>   app ...

You can use "adb push" command as

```
adb push <filename> <target>
```

(see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html for more details), **or simply use** "File Explorer" in DDMS perspective then select a folder in sd card folder and select "push a file on to device" to place your files in that folder in your emulator:
[image]

And you can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

to access sd-card absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to save some files in your emulator sdcard 
then ddms->file explorer->sdcard then push a file into device as shown in image

[image]

when you click on the icon notified by circle a browse dialog will come then browse your file and as you select save file will be saved in sdcard of emulator

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the below tutorial you will get some details about SD card usage in emulator.

[Android Tutorial: Creating and Using an SD Card in the Emulator](http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/)